# Replacing values in columns based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
        POLY_KEY_I         SP1        SP2
0     FS01080100SM001       POAPRA    TOXRYD
1     FS01080100SM001       NaN       NaN
2     FS01080100SM001       OXRYD     SYMOCC
3     FS01080100SM001       EUPESU    POAPRA
4     FS01080100SM001       BOUGRA    KOEPYR
5     FS01080100SM002       POAPRA    EUPESU
6     FS01080100SM002       POAPRA    NaN
7     FS01080100SM002       POAPRA    KOEPYR
```

and I want to replace `NaN` within `SP2` only if there is a non `NaN` value in `SP1`.  If this happens I want to replace it with the value in `SP1`.  My desired output is this:

```
        POLY_KEY_I         SP1        SP2
0     FS01080100SM001       POAPRA    TOXRYD
1     FS01080100SM001       NaN       NaN
2     FS01080100SM001       OXRYD     SYMOCC
3     FS01080100SM001       EUPESU    POAPRA
4     FS01080100SM001       BOUGRA    KOEPYR
5     FS01080100SM002       POAPRA    EUPESU
6     FS01080100SM002       POAPRA    POAPRA
7     FS01080100SM002       POAPRA    KOEPYR
```

there are about 100 unique values within `SP1` so I can't just do it manually because I don't always know what the string in `SP1` will be.

EDIT: 
Another way that would work for me is to say if `SP2` == `NaN`  return the value from `SP1`

I have tried this code, but it gives the string SP1 (obviously) and I am not sure how to return the actual value.  Here is the code:

```
def f(x):
  if x['SP2'] == 'NaN' : return 'SP1'
df['SP2'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)    
print df
```

Comment: not quite, for all values that don't have `NaN` in `SP2` they are turned to `none`.  I want to retain the original values still.  It does work on the rows that do have `NaN` for `SP2` though.

Comment: `else: return x['SP2']`

Answer (score 0):

How is this?

```
df['SP2'][pandas.isnull(df['SP2'])] = df['SP1']
```

In the case where SP1 and SP2 are both NaN you just copy the NaN as well

Answer (score 0):

Use `loc` and a boolean mask to overwrite the values, it's irrelevant if 'SP1' is already `NaN` as the result is the same:

```
In [244]:
df.loc[df['SP2'].isnull(), 'SP2'] = df['SP1']
df

Out[244]:
        POLY_KEY_I     SP1     SP2
0  FS01080100SM001  POAPRA  TOXRYD
1  FS01080100SM001     NaN     NaN
2  FS01080100SM001   OXRYD  SYMOCC
3  FS01080100SM001  EUPESU  POAPRA
4  FS01080100SM001  BOUGRA  KOEPYR
5  FS01080100SM002  POAPRA  EUPESU
6  FS01080100SM002  POAPRA  POAPRA
7  FS01080100SM002  POAPRA  KOEPYR
```

If you want to use a conditional to return a particular column if not `NaN` and another column if so, you can use np.where:

```
In [246]:
np.where(df['SP2'].notnull(), df['SP2'], df['SP1'])

Out[246]:
array(['TOXRYD', nan, 'SYMOCC', 'POAPRA', 'KOEPYR', 'EUPESU', 'POAPRA',
       'KOEPYR'], dtype=object)
```